# Write text input on the screen in SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

So I'm creating a graphing calculator. I have an input string s. From the string, I can graph it using SFML. I start from the a MIN x-coordinate to a MAX x-coordinate, get the corresponding y from a EvaluateString() method,  and all the coordinates to a VertexArray v. I wrote my method and the graphing method already and it all worked well.

However, I have a small issue. I want to input my string on the screen, such as "sin(cos(tan(x)))" like this. I'm struggling to find a way to do it. I kinda figured out it has to do with the event TextEntered, but still I can't find anything completely.

Please suggest me a way.

[image: Sample graph]

```
class Calculator{
public:
    void main();
private:
    WindowSize DefaultWindow;
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    Cartesian vertexX[2],vertexY[2];
    sf::Vertex axis[4];
    const double MAX = 10;
    const double MIN = -10;
    const double INCREMENT = 0.001;

};

int main(){ 
    DefaultWindow.Max = Cartesian(10,10);
    DefaultWindow.Min = Cartesian(-10,-10);
    DefaultWindow.plane.width=1500;
    DefaultWindow.plane.height=1500;

    // Set up x and y-axis
    vertexX[0] = Cartesian(-100,0);
    vertexX[1] = Cartesian(100, 0);
    vertexY[0] = Cartesian(0,-100);
    vertexY[1] = Cartesian(0,100);

    axis[0] = sf::Vertex(convertCartesiantoWindow(vertexX[0],DefaultWindow));
    axis[1] = sf::Vertex(convertCartesiantoWindow(vertexX[1],DefaultWindow));
    axis[2] = sf::Vertex(convertCartesiantoWindow(vertexY[0],DefaultWindow));
    axis[3] = sf::Vertex(convertCartesiantoWindow(vertexY[1],DefaultWindow));

    // Set up the window
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(1500, 1500), "Graphing calculator");

    // Input string
    string s = "sin(cos(tan(x)))";

    // Stack c contains all the Cartesian coordinate vertices
    // Cartesian is a struct which contains x and y coordinates
    Stack<Cartesian> c;

    sf::VertexArray v;

    // For a certain function in string s, I evaluate it 
    // and return the y_coordinate from the function EvaluateString (s, i)
    // Push each (x,y) evaluated in the Stack c
    for (double i = MIN; i <= MAX; i+= INCREMENT)
        c.Push(Cartesian(i,EvaluateString(s,i)));

    // v is VertexArray which contains all the vertices (x,y)
    v = plot(DefaultWindow, c);


    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {

            switch (event.type) {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Draw the graph
    window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
    window.draw(axis,4,sf::Lines);
    window.draw(v);
    window.display();
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/graphics-fonts.php` ?

Comment: @fang: Yes, it's only about drawing text. I want to input text on screen :(

Comment: [ImGui can be used in SFML](https://github.com/eliasdaler/imgui-sfml). It's a bit overkill for just achieving this, but if you need more GUI elements in your little project it could probably be very worthwhile to have a look at.

Comment: @super: can you tell me which part I should look at? I just get started with SFML, so reading about another library will overwhelm me a bit :)

Comment: @BrandonWilliams Once you have the set-up all you need is in the 20-line example in the link. Just replace `ImGui::Button` with `ImGui::InputText`, supply a buffer and the size of the buffer and your set.

Comment: @super: Thanks a lot. I heard of TGUI as well. Are they the same thing to do this?

Comment: No, they are very different. TGUI is good, and a more "standard" gui-library. If you are interested is customizing your GUI a lot or if the visual aspects are important then TGUI is probably a better choice. If you need something more fast and functional then ImGui be a great fit.

Comment: @super: So I put ImGUI + SFML together with ImGUI files from ocornut, but the ImGUI + SFML has some errors. I'm still struggling to find a way to just put a simple text entry field in SFML. If you have any idea, I will really appreciate

Comment: One idea is to solve the errors you are getting. Another is to follow Xion's answer. As Galik is pointing out in the comments you need a `sf::Text` to draw to the screen though. Not a `sf::String`. But the general idea is the right one. Catch `TextEntered` events, save it to a buffer, draw the buffer to the screen with `sf::Text`.

Answer (score 12):

As [@super suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734084/write-text-input-on-the-screen-in-sfml-c#comment94322472_53734084), use a library would be a nice solution, and surely better than mine, but just in case this satisfies your needs, I implemented a *super basic* `TextField` class.

It may be plenty of errors, but it can gives you an idea on how to achieve that functionality.

A `TextField` is nothing more than a **rectangle** which contains a **text**. Since it will have a `sf::Text`, it must have a `sf::Font`. Additionally, I **limit** the number of characters that it will contain. In order for us to write inside the `TextField`, we have to know if it's selected, i.e. if it has the **focus**. So, a first approach could be:

```
class TextField : public sf::Transformable, public sf::Drawable{
    private:
        unsigned int m_size;
        sf::Font m_font;
        std::string m_text;
        sf::RectangleShape m_rect;
        bool m_hasfocus;
};
```

We need a constructor for this class:

```
class TextField : public sf::Transformable, public sf::Drawable{
    public:
        TextField(unsigned int maxChars) :
            m_size(maxChars),
            m_rect(sf::Vector2f(15 * m_size, 20)), // 15 pixels per char, 20 pixels height, you can tweak
            m_hasfocus(false)
        {
            m_font.loadFromFile("C:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf"); // I'm working on Windows, you can put your own font instead
            m_rect.setOutlineThickness(2);
            m_rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
            m_rect.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(127,127,127));
            m_rect.setPosition(this->getPosition());
        }

    private:
        unsigned int m_size;
        sf::Font m_font;
        std::string m_text;
        sf::RectangleShape m_rect;
        bool m_hasfocus;
};
```

We also need some basic methods, we want to get the text inside:

```
const std::string sf::TextField::getText() const{
    return m_text;
}
```

and move it, placing it somewhere inside our window:

```
void sf::TextField::setPosition(float x, float y){
    sf::Transformable::setPosition(x, y);
    m_rect.setPosition(x, y);
}
```

this is a tricky one. We are overwritting `setPosition` [method](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1Transformable.php#a4dbfb1a7c80688b0b4c477d706550208) of `sf::Transformable` because we need to update our own `m_rect`.

Also, we need to know if a point is inside of the box:

```
bool sf::TextField::contains(sf::Vector2f point) const{
    return m_rect.getGlobalBounds().contains(point);
}
```

pretty simple, we use `cointains` method of `sf::RectangleShape`, already in [sfml](/questions/tagged/sfml).

Set (or unset) focus on the `TextField`:

```
void sf::TextField::setFocus(bool focus){
    m_hasfocus = focus;
    if (focus){
        m_rect.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Blue);
    }
    else{
        m_rect.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(127, 127, 127)); // Gray color
    }
}
```

easy one. For aesthetics, we also change the outline color of the box when focused.

And last, but not least, our `TextField` has to behave some way when input (aka an `sf::Event`) is received:

```
void sf::TextField::handleInput(sf::Event e){
    if (!m_hasfocus || e.type != sf::Event::TextEntered)
        return;

    if (e.text.unicode == 8){   // Delete key
        m_text = m_text.substr(0, m_text.size() - 1);
    }
    else if (m_text.size() < m_size){
        m_text += e.text.unicode;
    }
}
```

That delete key check is little dirty, I know. Maybe you can find better solution.

That's all! Now `main` looks like:

```
int main()
{
    RenderWindow window({ 500, 500 }, "SFML", Style::Close);

    sf::TextField tf(20);
    tf.setPosition(30, 30);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        for (Event event; window.pollEvent(event);)
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
            else if (event.type == Event::MouseButtonReleased){
                auto pos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
                tf.setFocus(false);
                if (tf.contains(sf::Vector2f(pos))){
                    tf.setFocus(true);
                }
            }
            else{
                tf.handleInput(event);
            }

            window.clear();
            window.draw(tf);
            window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Proof of concept:

[image]

Comment: Random code review comment after following your post on Meta: reduce nesting in `void sf::TextField::handleInput(sf::Event e){` by inverting conditions and returning early: 

`if (!m_hasfocus || e.type != sf::Event::TextEntered) return;`
 Then combine the following`else` into `else if`: `else if (m_text.size() < m_size)` Then you can finally drop the curly braces and your overall function is much cleaner and easier to read. If you'd like a metric, the cognitive complexity score is improved.

Comment: I don't see the `draw()` method of your text input class, but still i don't see why you implement `setPosition()` and inherit from `sf::Transformable` at the same time. Since you inherited from it, let it handle the position and just use `states.transform *= this->getTransform(); target.draw(m_rect, states);` in the draw method.

Answer (score -2):

```
std::string str;
sf::String text;

// In event loop...
if (event.Type == sf::Event::TextEntered)
{
    // Handle ASCII characters only
    if (event.Text.Unicode < 128)
    {
        str += static_cast<char>(event.Text.Unicode);
        text.SetText(str);
    }
}

// In main loop...
window.Draw(text);
```

This should create an sf::Event::TextEntered for input, and sf::String for output

Comment: Can you help me understand this? How can I input to a certain textbook out of this?

Comment: Is `sf::String` *drawable* like this? I think you may need `sf::Text`.