# How can i make a clickable button in console using C++?

Tags: button, console-application, c++20

I'm just trying to make a project in console. I want to add some buttons. Is there a way to add a clickable button in console?

I tried to find some information, but I couldn't find anything. Some information says to use some graphics library like SFML. Is it really impossible?

Comment: No there is not you need to use a GUI library of some sort or write your own. tcl/tk, and ncurses are some other example libraries as well as gtk and qt.

Comment: You can implement your own button component. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734084/write-text-input-on-the-screen-in-sfml/53765163#53765163) I explained how to implement a Text Input, but a button will be much easier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The console is not usually used as a standard GUI, so no, you cannot add a clickable button to the console.

However, you can create your own GUI app using for instance SFML, as you mentioned, which is, however, especially for making 2D games rather than GUI apps with buttons, although it could be used for that purpose.

If you want to create a GUI app with buttons and etc., you can have a look at [Qt framework](https://www.qt.io/product/framework) or [ImGui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui) or any other C++ GUI library.

For the other alternatives check:
[Gui toolkits, which should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584734/gui-toolkits-which-should-i-use)